# '×' multiplication symbol replaces &timestamp in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a link, which generates from GoCardless PHP library.
I'm using WordPress and I've found that the file `/wp-includes/formatting.php` have a function `"ent2ncr"`, which replaces `"&times"` with multiplication sign `"&#215"` and in some magical way, this function ( may be I'm wrong ) changes `...&timestamp=2017-08-24T12%3A26%3A34Z` to `...×tamp=2017-08-24T12%3A26%3A34Z`

I can't change a name of this parameter, because it is required by GoCarldess API.

P.S. I've tried to comment this line in `formatting.php`, but nothing changes.

Comment: If nothing changes then it is just browser output. Take link and provide it to api, it is working?

Comment: Yes, link works if &timestamp is there instead of ×tamp

Comment: Once again - when you see `×` it is just representation in a browser. It does not change the string itself. Please do usual operations with this string, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: But GoCardless API doesn't understand that link and I have an error - Timestamp can't be blank.

Comment: You copypaste that link or what?

Comment: So, steps:
1) GoCardless lib generates a link and param &timestamp already replaced with ×tamp for some reason
2) User should be redirected to that link, but nothing happens, because if there are errors in response, browser doesn't redirect to that link.
3) If I replace manually that part of link to &timestamp, everything is fine

Comment: You should be encoding your URLs before outputting them anyway.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats happening is the &times part of &timestamp is being translated as `x`
as a result you end up with xtamp

Try encoding the `&` in front of `timestamp` with `&amp;`

edited: to say encoding not escaping

Comment: It's not escaping the `&`, it's encoding it.

Answer (score 1):

**I had ever meet a question with ×(&times) and then fixed below by use htmlentities**

```
$str = $node->getAttribute('href');
echo $str;//output http://mp.weixin.qq.com/profile? 
src=3×tamp=1524825376&ver=1  
echo htmlentities($str);
```

[here](http://mp.weixin.qq.com/profile?src=3&timestamp=1524825376&ver=1) is the output