# Verify that Embedded app settings page visit is from Shopify in PHP

Tags: php, shopify, hmac

When a client installs the app, they have the option to click on the app name in the list of apps on the `/admin/apps` page.

When they click that page, my PHP index file for my app receives these `$_GET` vars:

```
hmac = some_long_alphanumaeric_hmac
locale = en
protocol = https://
shop = example-shop.myshopify.com
timestamp = 1535609063
```

To verify a webhook from Shopify, I successfully use this:

```
function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header, $app_api_secret) {
    $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $app_api_secret, true));
    return ($hmac_header == $calculated_hmac);
}

// Set vars for Shopify webhook verification
$hmac_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header, MY_APP_API_SECRET);
```

Is it possible to verify an app admin page visit is from a Shopify client that has the app installed?

PS: I've looked through both, the [Embedded Apps API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/embedded-app-sdk/getting-started) (but I can't figure out if that's even the right documentation or if I'm doing something wrong), as well as the [GitHub example provided](https://github.com/Sovi-Creative/shopify-embedded-app-blog-example/blob/master/views/index.ejs) (which has no instructions on how to verify an Embedded App admin page visit).

#### UPDATE:

I've tried various other ways, discovering some ridiculous problems along the way, but still no luck.

1. The method I understand should be used to verify a Shopify HMAC is something akin to this:

   ```
   function verify_hmac($hmac = NULL, $shopify_app_api_secret) {
       $params_array = array();
       $hmac = $hmac ? $hmac : $_GET['hmac'];
       unset($_GET['hmac']);

       foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
           $key = str_replace("%","%25",$key);
           $key = str_replace("&","%26",$key);
           $key = str_replace("=","%3D",$key);
           $value = str_replace("%","%25",$value);
           $value = str_replace("&","%26",$value);
           $params_array[] = $key . "=" . $value;
       }

       $params_string = join('&', $params_array);
       $computed_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $params_string, $shopify_app_api_secret);

       return hash_equals($hmac, $computed_hmac);
   }
   ```

But the line `$params_string = join('&', $params_array);` causes an annoying problem by encoding `&timestamp` as `xtamp` ... Using `http_build_query($params_array)` results in the same ridiculous thing.  Found others having this same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866266/%C3%97-multiplication-symbol-replaces-timestamp-in-url).  Basically resolved by encoding the `&` as `&amp;`, to arrive at `$params_string = join('&amp;', $params_array);`.

2. My final version is like this, but still doesn't work (all the commented code is what else I've tried to no avail):

   ```
   function verify_hmac($hmac = NULL, $shopify_app_api_secret) {
       $params_array = array();
       $hmac = $hmac ? $hmac : $_GET['hmac'];
       unset($_GET['hmac']);
   //  unset($_GET['protocol']);
   //  unset($_GET['locale']);

       foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
           $key = str_replace("%","%25",$key);
           $key = str_replace("&","%26",$key);
           $key = str_replace("=","%3D",$key);
           $value = str_replace("%","%25",$value);
           $value = str_replace("&","%26",$value);
           $params_array[] = $key . "=" . $value;
   //  This commented out method below was an attempt to see if 
   //  the imporperly encoded query param characters were causing issues
   /*
           if (!isset($params_string) || empty($params_string)) {
               $params_string = $key . "=" . $value;
           }
           else {
               $params_string = $params_string . "&amp;" . $key . "=" . $value;
           }
   */
       }

   //  $params_string = join('&amp;', $params_array);
   //  echo $params_string;
   //  $computed_hmac =  base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $params_string, $shopify_app_api_secret, true));
   //  $computed_hmac =  base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $params_string, $shopify_app_api_secret, false));
   //  $computed_hmac =  hash_hmac('sha256', $params_string, $shopify_app_api_secret, false);
   //  $computed_hmac =  hash_hmac('sha256', $params_string, $shopify_app_api_secret, true);
       $computed_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($params_array), $shopify_app_api_secret);

       return hash_equals($hmac, $computed_hmac);
   }
   ```

Comment: _“Is it possible to verify an app admin page visit is from a Shopify client that has the app installed?”_ - as opposed to - what exactly? And are you trying to get this only for information/app workflow purposes, or is this supposed to be “security related” in any way?

Comment: Security, similar to that of a webhook (the method above is used to verify a webhook as coming from Shopify).

Comment: Well if you still get an hmac value passed as a GET parameter in this situation, then presumably you can validate that pretty much the same way …?

Comment: I thought so too, but either it's not possible in this situation to verify the same way, or I'm doing it wrong.  For webhook verification, the calculated HMAC comes from the request header HMAC + received data + Shopify App Secret.  Using the same equation to verify an app admin page visit from Shopify's admin panel, doesn't send any data, and the verification fails (if using the same method as webhook).

Comment: _“causes an annoying problem by encoding `&timestamp` as `xtamp`”_ - nah, that’s just your browser fooling you, by interpreting this as the HTML entity `&times;`, which represents the `×` character.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Im facing the same issue

Comment: My app has been working for a couple months but all of a sudden I am also now facing this issue. Code no longer works. It actually works on the test version of my app but not production. I've spent hours on this. Have Shopify changed the way they calculate hmac or something???

Comment: I'm not sure, still haven't figured it out yet.  I'm pretty sure at this point that all Shopify backend admin settings pages are simply insecure.  I can't find documentation on how to verify Shopify backend admin app settings page requests.  There's dos on how to get auth token and verify on install and how to verify webhooks, but not backend admin app settings.

Comment: @ThomasLang Did you get this working? I resorted to using simple AuthenticatedController without WebhookVerification. Probably doesn't matter where user came from (from admin page or by typing URL directly) as long as he has access to the page.

Comment: @Zmey, yes I got it working, somehow my app secret and api key werent calculating the right hmac hash.. I created a new app, and with the new API key and secret my code worked again.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a hit from Shopify, the first thing you do is check in your persistence layer if you have the shop registered. If you do, and you have a session of some kind setup, you are free to render your App to that shop. If you do not have the shop persisted, you go through the oAuth cycle to get an authentication token to use on the shop, which you persist along with the shop and new session.

For any routes or end points in your shop where you are receiving webhooks, of course those requests have no session, so you use the HMAC security approach to figure out what to do. So your question is clearly straddling two different concepts, each handled differently. The documentation is pretty clear on the differences.

Comment: What I don't understand is *how to verify that it's actually from Shopify?*  The only indicators are the query params (ie, "shop"), but that can easily be faked. 
"The documentation is pretty clear on the differences." -  where, mind pointing it out (I'm guessing you have it open to that page and paragraph to make this claim)?

Comment: I explained it to you. If you get a request with just a shop parameter, and you have not established a session, you have to look it up in your persistence layer, or do the oAuth shuffle to get a token.

Comment: I think that's incorrect.  I already have a token from the install, and that along with webhooks/webhook verification is working flawlessly.  If I just retrieve any of the stored access token data that I received on install (ie, code), because some request sent me a shop parameter, that would simply be insecure and defeat the purpose of verifying the specific call I've received.  It could just be you sending my script a request with the `shop=whatever-you-want.myshopify.com`.  Nor can I perform a new OAuth "shuffle as I haven't received a new `code`. Thanks tho.

Comment: You miss the logic. If you get a shop=whatever.myshopify.com request, and it fails the "is there a session test", you get the chance to decide what to do. If there is that shop in your persistence layer, you get a valid token, so you setup a session and carry on. If not, you do the oAuth shuffle by redirecting to /login. Simple. Secure. No brainer :)

Comment: You lose me at `it fails the "is there a session test"`, as I don't understand the session reference.  Yes, I am ignorant.  I've built a fairly "robust" PHP app for my company, with users/logins/db-storage (mongo And MySQL)/sessions.... I get sessions here.  But I haven't seen anything on sessions in the Shopify docs, so I am completely lost once you mention sessions/persistence layer.  If you ever feel like taking the time to explain it to me, or forward me a link to docs you happen to run into, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: It is the same. PHP, Ruby, Python, all exactly the same. Shopify operates the same as Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc. Just follow the same pattern as 99.9% of other Apps and you'll get it. Shopify has no interest in explaining to developers how to write an App, as that is covered by the rest of the world just fine. They should and do only care about the specifics of their endpoints that matter, what webhooks they publish, and the rules. They do not care to explain a basic HTTP GET or POST, as that is not their business to explain.

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable, though probably incorrect due to their business interests in seeing more people build apps, and also seems utterly irrelevant.  You're talking to someone who has built several perfectly functioning apps for Shopify.  `They do not care to explain a basic HTTP GET or POST` -- good, cuz it's utterly unnecessary.  What is needed is documentation on their embedded app interface, and the iFrame it loads in, and how authentication is done in that interface when they send the HMAC as a `$_GET` parameter.  You've convinced me you do not understand the question, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant documentation: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth#verification. This info by Sandeep was also very helpful too: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/HMAC-verify-app-install-request-using-php/m-p/140097#comment-253000.

Here is what worked for me:

```
function verify_visiter() // returns true or false
{
  // check that timestamp is recent to ensure that this is not a 'replay' of a request that has been intercepted previously (man in the middle attack)
  if (!isset($_GET['timestamp'])) return false;
    $seconds_in_a_day = 24 * 60 * 60;
    $older_than_a_day = $_GET['timestamp'] < (time() - $seconds_in_a_day);
    if ($older_than_a_day) return false;
  $shared_secret = Your_Shopify_app_shared_secret;
  $hmac_header = $_GET['hmac'];
  unset($_GET['hmac']);
  $data = urldecode(http_build_query($_GET));
  $calculated_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $shared_secret, false);
  return hash_equals($hmac_header, $calculated_hmac);
}

$verified = verify_visiter();

if (!$verified) {
  exit('User verification failed.');
}

// ... everything else...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function authenticateCalls($data = NULL, $bypassTimeCheck = FALSE)
{
    $da = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
    {
        $da[$key] = $val; 
    }
    if(isset($da['hmac']))
    {
        unset($da['hmac']);
    }   
            
    ksort($da); 
    
    // Timestamp check; 1 hour tolerance
    if (!$bypassTimeCheck)
    {
        if (($da['timestamp'] - time() > 3600))
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    
    // HMAC Validation
    $queryString = http_build_query($da);
    $match = $data['hmac'];
    $calculated = hash_hmac('sha256', $queryString, $this->_API['API_SECRET']);
    
    return $calculated === $match;
}
```

Comment: Please always explain your code and what the solution is all about and what the problem of the OP was and how it was solved. Code alone will often not help the Original poster to solve its problem. Also note that the OP already solved it 2 years ago.